# Trying to get shading and glowing effect

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I get this golden shining effect (pict) within a node, more precisely the text?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,mult,convert={density=300,size=1080x800,outext=.png}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\definecolor{amber2}{RGB}{239, 215, 74}





\def\MD{ 
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \i in {0,100}{
        \node [circle, fill=orange, font=\centering \Huge ,align=center, rotate=0, text=amber2] 
        (symbol) at (-1.25,1/8+\i/4000) {MB};}
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{document}
\MD
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you may lookup `fadingfrompicture`.

Comment: I did my best but couldn't work it out:(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\node[white] {\Huge MB};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{amber2}{RGB}{239, 215, 74}
\fill[orange] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\fill[path fading=myfading, left color=amber2, right color =white, shading angle=45] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: "MB" in circle]

-or with a ball effect:

```
documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
\node[white] {\Huge \textbf MB};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\definecolor{amber2}{RGB}{239, 215, 74}
\fill[orange] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\fill[path fading=myfading, ball color=amber2, shading angle=300] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: "MB" shaded with ball effect in a circle]

Comment: I love the one with ball effect !!!