# Putting colors and symbols inside symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

I need to embed the flower and its color into `\dh`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=myfading]
    \node[white] {\Huge \textbf \dh};
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \fill[red] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
        \fill[path fading=myfading, ball color=white, shading angle=300] (0,0) circle[radius=1];
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The desired output is the same except `\dh` has to have the following color and the flower ,inside, as shown in the following picture:

[image]

The red background remains the same.

CREDITS to [hpekristiansen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/605191/185467)

Comment: I believe you would have to convert \dh into a tikz path in order to apply a fading or shading.  Colors are easy, but not shadings.

Comment: I imagined shadings weren't easy. If you wanna give it a try, that'd be awesome! I'm useless when it comes to tikz :(

Comment: If I were to try something like this, I would use a graphics editor (like GIIMP) instead of tikz.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194211/draw-realistic-clouds-with-tikz/194567?r=SearchResults&s=1|24.6453#194567 for example.